# Parsing JSON in c# (.NET2.0 / JSON.NET35)

Tags: c#, json, rest, json.net

I have to customize a software which uses .net 2.0.
My task is to integrate a JSON REST API. For these purposes I am trying to use json.net which works fine for the calls.
Trying to parse the results I came up with this:

```
using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webStream))
{
    try
    {
          JsonTextReader jsonreader = new JsonTextReader(responseReader);
          while (jsonreader.Read())
          {
          if (jsonreader.Path == "data.key" && jsonreader.TokenType == JsonToken.String) return jsonreader.Value.ToString();
          }
          throw new Exception("no token found in answer");
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
          // error handling
          throw;
     }
}
```

This works fine on newer versions of Json.NET. Unfortunately, JsonTextReader.Path is not available in this version (3.5) and there is no chance to upgrade.
How can I parse the result to receive the given token under the attributes data->key?

The response looks like this

> {   "status": {
>       "code": 0,
>       "httpStatus": 200,
>       "text": "Request successful submitted",
>       "success": true   },   "data": {
>       "key": "dIwbU9ZjQDH6P95aMqs%2Bh%AKLA22%2ByeY2R7PC6IknkWC%2BlrmcN%2Blm5F3WNBa027gTm%0D%0A2zp5NGC1X2NON72A7N%2BZjB2fxJizUg0paiVdWlv4K1ZSKLlIGprTVoaMHqA1%0D%0AcfCHnV6E%0D%0A"
>   },   "success": true }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Json.Net v3.5 is rather old now, but something like this should work.

Replace this:

```
while (jsonreader.Read())
{
    if (jsonreader.Path == "data.key" && jsonreader.TokenType == JsonToken.String)
        return jsonreader.Value.ToString();
}
```

with this:

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);
return obj["data"]["key"].ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very useful! For addition: The tokenstring in this example can be retrieved by responseReader.ReadToEnd()